# How to fix size of child divs with content into parent div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I have some issues with div sizing when I resize browser window. I want child divs always remain inside the parent div and decrease in size proportionally to parent div when browser window resizing. I guess it should be a javascript but I dont  know which one exactly and how to use it. Any advice will be appreciated!

```
     #parent
    {
     position: fixed;
     width: 100%;
     height:    11%;
     background-color: white;
     left: 0;

    } 

    #child1
    {
   left: 100px;  
   position:absolute;     

    }

    #child2
    {
      position: absolute;
      left: 700px;   
      margin-top: 15px;    
      font-size: 1.5em; 

    }



    <div id="parent">

          <div id="child1">
         <a> <img src="img\linkedin.png" alt="jhj" width="200px;" height="70px;" />   </a>

          </div>  

          <div id="child2"> <a>Home</a>  <a>Examples</a> <a>Tricks</a> <a>Contact us</a> 
          </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: If you have the value of properties in css in %, then it will resize proportionally.

Comment: Your childs absolute position should be `right: 0; bottom:0; top: 0`

Comment: Thank you for your answers! For now it solved the problem with child1 but neither from all responses did not do anything with child2..Text is still going out of parent div when resizing

Answer (score 0):

To be able to affect to the parent div the *#child2* should be `position: relative;` like this:

```css
  #child2 {
    position: relative;
    top: 15;
    margin-top: 0;
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/eapo/1tkqsm5q/

Comment: Thank you for your answers! For now it solved the problem with child1 but neither from all responses did not do anything with child2..Text is still going out of parent div when resizing

Comment: something is not clear about your comment, i was writing about #child2.. and solves your problem with that. please use jsfiddle.net

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ddpjy857/        the difference between yours and that one in height property in parent.. If I use your code parent div will be too thin, but when I adding height problems with resizing appear again.

Comment: oops I guess I  have just solved it by myself  by using margin-top property in child2 .. Anyway thank you!! You helped a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the styles for both children to the following:

```
#child1 {
    left: 100px;  
    position:absolute;     
    width: 50%;
}

#child2 {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 50%;
    margin-top: 15px;
    font-size: 1.5em;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers! For now it solved the problem with child1 but neither from all responses did not do anything with child2..Text is still going out of parent div when resizing